# Angular8 - focus on multiple inputs by dropdown(select) value dynamically

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm new in Angular8. I have some requirements for setting focus on different inputs by dropdown(select) value.

I've tried some stuff like event.target.attributes.id /event.currenttarget, but I know it's impossible.

How would I be able to do this?

```
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-test',
          template: '
         <div> 
              <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="dropValue" (change)="dropChanged($event)>
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value=1>Cat</option>
              <option value=2>Dog</option>
              </select>
        </div>

         <div>
              <input id="CatInput" class="form-control"/>
              <input id="DogInput" class="form-control"/>
         </div>'

        })

export class test implements OnInit {
   dropValue:number;
   constructor() {
      this.dropValue = 0;
   }

   ngOnInit() {}

   dropChanged(e:any) {

      let dropName = e.target.id;

      switch (dropName) {
         case 'CatInput': 
              dropName.focus() or XXX <== I have no idea!!
         break;

         case 'DogInput': 
              dropName.focus() XXX <==  I have no idea!!
         break;
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Angular it's use template reference variables

You can choose give the same template reference to yours inputs and use ViewChildren

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control" [ngModel]="dropValue"
         (ngModelChange)="dropValue=$event;focus($event)">
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value=1>Cat</option>
         <option value=2>Dog</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
    <input #input id="CatInput" class="form-control"/>
    <input #input id="DogInput" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

In your .ts you defined

```
  dropValue:any
  @ViewChildren('input') inputs:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

And your function focus, you find in the QueryList the element with a "id" choose

```
focus(value)
  {
    let id="";
    switch (+value)
    {
      case 1:
        id="CatInput"
        break;
      case 2:
        id="DogInput"
        break;
    }
    if (id)
    {
      const input=this.inputs.find(x=>x.nativeElement.getAttribute('id')==id)
      if (input)
        input.nativeElement.focus()
    }
  }
```

You can also take another aproach that is use different template variable reference for each input

```
<div>
    <input #catID class="form-control"/>
    <input #dogID class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

In select, you can use [ngValue] in option to create an object with value and id and use this "id" to make the focus. see that you needn't write code in .ts

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="dropValue" 
       (ngModelChange)="dropValue=$event;$event?.id.focus()">
     <option [ngValue]="null">Select</option>
     <option [ngValue]="{value:1,id:catID}">Cat</option>
     <option [ngValue]="{value:2,id:dogID}">Dog</option>
</select>
```

See the two options in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tpepq9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

NOTE:

```
//I prefer
<input [ngModel]="variable" (ngModelChange)="variable=$event;function()">

//than 
<input [(ngModel)]="variable" (change)="function()">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works well for me.I will try to change my coding style likes your note.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use elementref / viewchild to get foucs on the input box

```
   constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { // have element ref here
      this.dropValue = 0;
   }
```

**// Make a logic that is common b/w select and input**

like when you select something from UI suppose you selected cat that you know that there is a id catinput which i have to foucs on.

then you can use it to find the element and focus on that.

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#CatInput').focus();
```

have a look at below , i created this as a mini exmaple.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tu9snc

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngFor for the same.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="dropValue" (change)="dropChanged($event)>
<option *ngFor="let v of values; let i = index" [value]="index">{{v}}</option>
</select>
```

and in you .ts declare values as:

```
values = ['Select', 'Cat', 'Dog'];
```